# making a javascript variable visible in the whole script

Tags: javascript, variables

I got this

```
$('#password').change(function() {
    var toSha1 = $('#msisdn').val() + $('#password').val();
    var authCode = $.sha1(toSha1);
});
```

How can I make the variable authCode to be visible in the whole script. For example this to work properly:

```
  $('#password').change(function() {
    var toSha1 = $('#msisdn').val() + $('#password').val();
    var authCode = $.sha1(toSha1);
});
 alert(authCode);
```

I've tried by defining it without the keyword "var" but it seemed not to work.

EDITED: here's the source

```
<div data-role="content">
    <textarea id='resultArea'></textarea>
    <label for='msisdn'>MSISDN:</label>
    <input type='text' id='msisdn' value='+359899888777'>
    <label for='authCode'>authCode:</label>
    <input type='text' id='authCode' value='8bcac5dabf06219843a5a3b755c47e69600e050a'>
    <label for='password'>Password:</label>
    <input type='password' id='password' value='123'>
    <button data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-theme='e' id='register'>Register</button>
    <button data-role='button' data-inline='true' data-theme='e' id='login'>Login</button>
</div><!-- /content -->
<script>
$('#resultArea').hide();
$('#password').change(function() {
    var toSha1 = $('#msisdn').val() + $('#password').val();
    window.authCode = $.sha1(toSha1);
});
alert(window.authCode);
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it a global explicitly:

```
window.authCode = $.sha1(toSha1);
```

Global variables are properties of the `window` object.

Note that there's a separate issue with your code, though: You're alerting the value of `authCode` immediately after hooking up the handler, rather than when the `change` event fires. See the comments:

```
$('#resultArea').hide();               // Happens immediately
$('#password').change(function() {     // change() call happens immediately, setting up the handler
    // ...but this code runs when the handler is *called*, not inline with the code above and below
    var toSha1 = $('#msisdn').val() + $('#password').val();
    window.authCode = $.sha1(toSha1);
});
alert(window.authCode);                // Happens immediately after the calls above
```

Comment: ok i used window.authCode insted of var authCode and authCode, but when I use alert(authCode) nothing happens and when using alert(window.authCode) it prints "undefined" . Look at my first comment for the source

Comment: @user1113314: That's because your `alert` happens before the `change` event is ever fired.

Comment: Thank You very much! I've completely understood it :)

Answer (score 1):

**change:**

`var authCode = $.sha1(toSha1);`

**to**

`window.authCode = $.sha1(toSha1);`